# Mysql adding comments for table and columns at the same time cost a lot

Tags: mysql

here's my sql

```
alter table `third_party_order`
change column `THIRD_PARTY_ORDER_ID` `THIRD_PARTY_ORDER_ID` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'AAA',
change column `THIRD_PARTY_USER_ID` `THIRD_PARTY_USER_ID`   varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'BBB',
change column `SDK_TYPE` `SDK_TYPE`                         char(1)     NOT NULL COMMENT 'CCC',
COMMENT 'TABLE COMMENT',
algorithm = INPLACE;
```

this sql above costs more than ten minutes because of the large amount of data, (not changing the column definition, just adding comment)
so I split this sql into two:

```
alter table `third_party_order`
change column `THIRD_PARTY_ORDER_ID` `THIRD_PARTY_ORDER_ID` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'AAA',
change column `THIRD_PARTY_USER_ID` `THIRD_PARTY_USER_ID`   varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'BBB',
change column `SDK_TYPE` `SDK_TYPE`                         char(1)     NOT NULL COMMENT 'CCC';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

```
alter table `third_party_order` COMMENT 'TABLE COMMENT';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

these two sql cost just a little time, I just wonder why?

Comment: Is this repeatable?

Comment: @Strawberry you mean isolation level? it's read committed

Comment: And mysql version is 5.6.16